# Применение SQL Server

Tags: sql

Могу ли я использовать SQL в мобильной и десктопной разработках?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа.

Comment: Возможно, я неполно изложил я, но суть вопроса в следующем: где применяется  SQL помимо веба

Comment: @Programmer вопрос из области - где ещё применяется стамеска кроме столярной мастерской. Да где угодно, где нужно принимать, хранить данные и возвращать их по запросу.

Comment: Я бы даже сравнил этот вопрос со следующим: «где применяется математика помимо физики?» Ответ: там где это необходимо и целесообразно! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Судя по заголовку вы смешиваете понятия `SQL` - `structured query language` и программу (одну из многих), которая позволяет оперировать хранящимися в ней данными с помощью этого языка.

Для любой ОС можно, в теории, написать программу, которая будет хранить данные, которыми можно будет, с помощью этой программы оперировать на одном из множества диалектов `SQL`. И такие программы есть для большинства операционных систем.

Таким образом ответ таков - да, вы можете работать с SQL на разных платформах. Вы, разве что, не сможете найти готовых программ для SQL на каких-то экзотических или очень низкоуровневых платформах. При чём для первых вы сможете написать свою программу для этого.